# VS code remote connection: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')

Tags: visual-studio-code

VScode Error message

```bash
[18:33:55.749] Resolver error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at Object.a [as sanitizeConnectionToken] (/Users/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.84.0/out/extension.js:1:691806)
    at Object.C [as findRunningServer] (/Users/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.84.0/out/extension.js:1:626542)
    at async /Users/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.84.0/out/extension.js:1:622510
    at async T (/Users/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.84.0/out/extension.js:1:619351)
    at async Object.t.resolveWithLocalServer (/Users/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.84.0/out/extension.js:1:622460)
    at async Object.t.resolve (/Users/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.84.0/out/extension.js:1:644834)
    at async /Users/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.84.0/out/extension.js:1:727082
[18:33:55.751] ------
```

How to reproduce

- Keep the remote connection in VScode
- AFK (away from keyboard)
- When the connection naturally breaks, then retry to connect
- The error message will occur.

I found that one solution is to remove VScode cache at
`/Users/username/Library/Application\ Support/Code`

But this is definitely not the right way, any one knows the root cause and how to solve it?

Comment: I raised up an issue to VScode@github: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/155380

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, upgrading the remote SSH extension version to the pre-release version did not help me. What helped me though is [a suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6973#issuecomment-1227590034) mentioned by Lilei Zheng:

> I enabled "Remote Server Listen On Socket" option and it worked good so far.

This option is located in the "Remote - SSH" Extension Settings. I enabled it and I never had such problems again.

Answer (score 13):

I was able to fix this problem by upgrading the remote SSH extension version to the pre-release version.

Comment: which version you are using? I am at 0.84.6. Do you mean that switch to the pre-release version?

Comment: yes，i swtich to the pre-release version

Comment: It actually happened to me also on pre-release. But then - after switching to Stable problem was gone. So perhaps it's not a fix in particular version but the process of switching (reinstalling?) the extension...

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6973#issuecomment-1227590034  another suggestion here

Answer (score 2):

Mine was resolved after I updated my VSCode. It was actually asking me to restart it to apply the update, but I kept refusing it for a week.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was asking for my GPG passphrase and VSCode had no way of showing me the passphrase prompt.

I found out only when I used `git commit` in the terminal manually and then it asked for my passphrase. After entering it the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue in VSCode Insider since yesterday. The error went away after switching the remote - SSH extension from pre-release to release version.